# Confused by the meaning of ~なかな at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, expressions

> でも人通りが多すぎてちょっとうるさくない**なかあ**。近所付き合いが大変じゃないといいんだけど。

The sentences are regarding to the situation of renting an apartment.
For my own guessing, the first sentence probably means

> There are too many people passing by so it's very noisy

Then in this case why does the it use the negative expression うるさくない then followed by a weird ending word of **なかあ**?

Could anyone one help to explain the use of **なかあ** and the meaning of the whole sentence?

Comment: Does it really say なかあ and not かなあ?

Comment: @l'électeur It's from a N2 textbook called 日本語総まとめ Vocabulary. I googled it and there were two posts from other websites talking about this sentence. One of which has turned to be a private article and [the other](http://lang-8.com/734827/journals/41623176948498523453572435554919712864) didn't make sense at all.

Comment: Maybe it's a misprint?

Comment: ここでは「ないかなあ」になってますね→　https://quizlet.com/163067110/n211-flash-cards/

Comment: Thank you guys. I've decided to accept that it is a printing mistake.

Answer (score 1):

In Standard Japanese, the "sentence":

> 「でも人通{ひとどお}りが多{おお}すぎてちょっとうるさくない**なかあ**。」

makes no sense for the ending I have never seen/heard.

Even if that ending were "correct" or "normal" in a region somewhere, you would still not be required to be familiar with it for a standardized Japanese proficiency test.

If the ending were 「**かなあ**」 instead of 「なかあ」, however, the sentence (including the ending) would make perfect sense.  It would mean:

> "But I wonder if it might not be a bit too noisy from the heavy (pedestrian) traffic around here."